# max() Aggregation in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm creating a dashboard in Kibana with an index.

```
    Date | Place | Value
   ------|-------|-------
    12/16|LUXURY | 5
    12/16|LUXURY | 3
    12/16|LUXURY | 5
    12/16|LUXURY | 6
```

from the above records, I want to fetch only the record with maximum value (6).

simply, the logic should be **max(Value for Date,Place)** in many languages but I'm not sure about Kibana.  Please help me to create a column (new scripted field) for my visualization.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a bit more context as to what you are trying to do ? what have you done already ?

Comment: you could use aggregation request as documented here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation

Comment: You can use sort by `value desc` then [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)